# Should I use IsCancellationRequested from token or source when both are available?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

If I have a CancellationTokenSource that is still in scope when I'm checking for cancellation -- e.g., if I've just made a database query and have not yet passed the CancellationToken down to Tasks to process the results -- should I access IsCancellationRequested from the source or from its token?

In other words, if both options are available, which is preferred, and why?

1:

```
myCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested
```

2:

```
myCancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested
```

Comment: Verified from source, they are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular scenario, I believe the two are essentially equivalent.  I would prefer using the Token if only because this simplifies refactoring if you later split off the logic checking cancellation from the logic creating the cancellation source.  To further that end, I would store the token in a local reference and use that reference for the checking.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `myCancellationTokenSource` is used to initiate the cancellation (by a parent thread, for instance).  `myCancellationTokenSource.Token` is the associated `CancellationToken` that you would pass to something like `TaskFactory.StartNew()`.  The task would then monitor the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` to determine when to shut down.

Comment: Right... but what do I do when both options are available?  For instance, if I have a Windows service that makes a database call before I can start creating Tasks?  The database call could be long-running, and the operation might have been cancelled when my code comes back with the result.

Comment: If all you care about is that property, then there is no difference.  Internally, the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property is just returning the associated CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested property value.  Well, that's not entirely true.  Each time you reference Token, a new instance of CancellationToken is returned.  So, if you are doing one of those tests in a loop, you are better off not using the Token.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a token, although at least for variant 1 the effect is probably the same. CancellationTokens are read-only value types which are meant to be passed around the client code while the CancellationTokenSource is an IDisposable with some internal resources... For safety reasons I'd rather use it like this:

```
void MethodA() {
 // Context in which CancellationTokenSource is known
 using (var tSource = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
  ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem( pArg => MethodB(tSource.Token) );
  ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem( pArg => MethodC(tSource.Token) );
  // ...

  // some other work to do

  // cancel
  if (mSomethingHappend) {
   tSource.Cancel();
  }
 }
}

private static void MethodB( CancellationToken pToken )
{
 // ...
}
```